# Package name for a loop class

Tags: actionscript-3, naming, package, nomenclature

I wrote a class that performs an asynchronous loop. It needs a package name. I already have a util package, but feel resistant to put half of my classes in that package. If it really belongs there, I'll put it there, but I'd feel much better if I can find a more appropriate/specific package. What do you think?

Comment: can you post the code and the error msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with "timer" as the package name after finding many similarities with the Timer class that sits in the timer package.

Answer (score 1):

`peach` for parallel each.

Shamelessly stolen from the Ruby project [with the same name](http://peach.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A package is normally created for more than one class. If your class uses some helper classes, then it should go in a separate package; differently, you should use the generic package you already have.